# Построение части графика пунктирной линией

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть график примерно такого вида:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
y=[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3]
x=[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Как сделать что бы он не одной линией строился, а так сказать с разрывами (не знаю как это правильно называется, поэтому отрисовал в paint)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно вас понял, но разрывы в линиях можно сделать, если использовать `None`. А разные стили линий можно нарисовать отдельными командами:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
y=[5, 5, None, 4, 4, None, 3, 3]
x=[0, 1, None, 1, 2, None, 2, 3]
 
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')

y=[5, 4, None, 4, 3]
x=[1, 1, None, 2, 2]
 
plt.plot(x, y, 'b--')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что нужно!) Спасибо!